# #byteslice fails in correctly calculating the bytes in a string including accents

Tags: ruby, string, byte

I noticed that, when a given string includes accents, the `byteslice` method fails in returning the correct character, since Ruby apparently counts the bytes in the string in some weird way. That, or I'm missing something about how bytes in a string are calculated.

Here's a MWE:

```
text = "Càdiz"
puts text.byteslice(0)
puts text.byteslice(1)
puts text.byteslice(2)
puts text.byteslice(3)
puts text.byteslice(4)
```

The result I get in the terminal is this:

```
C
�
�
d
i
```

So, of course that accented letter is giving me troubles. Is this normal? Is there a way to always get the fifth character of a string in return, using `text.byteslice(4)` or some other similar method?

Comment: `text.bytes.size #=> 6` or `text.each_byte.size #=> 6` if you just want the total.

Comment: I don't want the total, I want a guaranteed way to get the character in a certain position  in a string which might vary, and that might include accents such in this case.

Comment: I started writing my answer before you wrote this comment, and now that I read your comment, I am no longer sure that my answer actually answers your question. It is quite confusing. In your subject line, you talk about bytes. In your second sentence, you talk about bytes. In your last paragraph, you talk about characters. In your comment, you talk about characters. Even more confusing, in the first sentence of your question, you talk about characters and bytes *within the same sentence*. So, which is it? Are you talking about characters or bytes?

Comment: Not `text[1] #=> "à"; text[2] #=> "d"`? If you want a character's byte(s), `text[1].bytes #=> [195, 160]; text[2].bytes #=> [100]`.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned I was most probably missing something about how bytes work. I thought that one character = one byte, since I couldn't find any other useful method in the ruby documentation. I didn't think about transforming the string in an array, as you did in your answer. Thank you ;)

Comment: "I thought that one character = one byte" – That may have been true when you learned to program in the 1970s, but it hasn't been true since the late 70s *at least*. In Asia, it has *never* been true. Bytes have historically been somewhere between 6 bits and 12 bits. 12 bits are *barely* enough for all Chinese characters. So, even with 12 bit bytes, bytes are simply too small to represent a character. There are over 3000 emoji characters, those *alone* need 1.5 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I noticed that, when a given string includes accents, the `byteslice` method fails in returning the correct character,

The [String#byteslice](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-byteslice) returns *bytes* not characters, so the fact that it would fail in returning a character should not be terribly surprising.

> since Ruby apparently counts the bytes in the string in some weird way.

I can't see anything weird about it. You asked it to return the second byte and it returned the second byte. UTF-8 is *specifically designed* in such a way that each individual byte of a multi-byte sequence is an illegal encoding, so if you split apart a character like that, it *cannot possibly* result in a legal character.

That is *by design*, it allows a UTF-8 stream decoder to self-synchronize.

> Is there a way to always get the fifth character of a string in return, using `text.byteslice(4)` or some other similar method?

No, there is no way to get the fifth *character* using `byteslice`, because `byteslice` is for *bytes*, not *characters*.

You *can*, however, get the fifth character using [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```ruby
text[4]
```

However, what you *probably* want is not the fifth *character* but the fifth *grapheme cluster*, and you can do that using the [`String#grapheme_clusters`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-grapheme_clusters) method:

```ruby
text.grapheme_clusters[4]
```

Let's look at my name, for example. There are two different ways to write my given name in Unicode:

1. J ö r g
2. J o <combining character diaeresis> r g

Note that the first version is *four* characters long, the second version is *five* characters long. Both have four *grapheme clusters*, though. However, note that while the *glyphs* are identical, the grapheme clusters are not.

The first version is encoded in ISO8859-15 in 4 bytes, but in UTF-8, it takes 5 bytes, in UTF-16, it takes 8 bytes, and and in UTF-32, it takes 16 bytes.

The second version cannot be encoded in ISO8859-15 because ISO8859-15 does not have the combining character dieresis. In fact, it has no combining characters at all. Encoding the second version in UTF-8 takes 6 bytes, UTF-16 10 bytes, UTF-32 20 bytes.

Let's assume the second example, and let's assume it is encoded in UTF-8. The string consists of the following *characters*:

1. U+004A Latin Capital Letter J
2. U+006F Lattin Small Letter o
3. U+0308 Combining Character Diaeresis
4. U+0072 Lattin Small Letter r
5. U+0067 Lattin Small Letter g

These are encoded into UTF-8 into this byte sequence:

1. `0x4A`
2. `0x6F`
3. `0xCC`
4. `0x88`
5. `0x72`
6. `0x67`

So, for example, if you were to ask for the third *byte*, you would get `0xCC`. And if you were to try and display that as a string, it would fail, because `0xCC` on its own is not a legal UTF-8 encoding. It is the first byte of a multi-byte sequence.

If you were to ask for the third *character*, you would get U+0308 Combining Character Diaeresis. If you were to try and display that as a string, it would fail, because a combining character without a base character doesn't make sense.

If you were to ask for the third *grapheme cluster*, you would get `'r'`, which is *probably* what you want.

So, in short: the reason you didn't get the character you wanted is that you didn't ask for a character, you asked for a byte. If you want a character, you need to ask for a character. However, what you *probably* want is a grapheme cluster, not a character.

In fact, grapheme clusters are *almost always* what you want.